# Can Alert prevent Surprise if you don't know combat is occurring yet?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, combat, initiative, surprise

If part of the party enters combat with enemies but the rest of the party is not aware of the threat or aware there is combat happening yet, does a player with the Alert feat who rolls highest on initiative act before even the enemies?

In this example, the Archer has the Alert feat but is hanging back behind a corner waiting for the Paladin to see if things are safe. The group rolls Initiative and the Archer rolls 21, the Spiders roll 15, and the Paladin rolls 8. The Spiders roll 24 for Stealth and Surprise the Paladin.

Who acts first? The only answers I come up with seem to unfairly negate the Archer's choice to take the Alert feat.

[image]

The relevant part of the Alert feat:

> You can't be surprised while you are conscious.

Comment: [Can an enemy surprise a character with the Alert feat by readying an action before Initiative is rolled?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/171520/can-an-enemy-surprise-a-character-with-the-alert-feat-by-readying-the-attack-a), [When exactly does combat start and surprise take effect?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124807/when-exactly-does-combat-start-and-surprise-take-effect), [What happens when your group is surprised but you can't be surprised?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150288/what-happens-when-your-group-is-victim-of-a-surprise-attack-but-you-cant-be-sur)

Comment: Also related - [Do attack rolls against a blinded character with the Alert feat have advantage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135041/31402)

Comment: Both the issues of how to handle 'split' parties for combat initiative and how to handle surprise in these cases is covered by the duplicated questions. Please let us know if you think those don't answer and what is missing.

Comment: @NautArch I believe this is a separate situation if you have everyone roll initiative but one has the Alert feat, such that it is not covered by the other two answers you posted. It is a combination of the two mechanics which makes it confusing to answer and adjudicate.

Comment: @Lexaire It is actually two questions in one. Unless you are saying that the archer most definitely is rolling initiative. In which guess it's a dupe of the first one, no? If you are unclear on whether or not the archer is participating in combat initiative, then it's the second one. But ultimately, is your question about "Do I include the archer in initiative?" or is it "does being unable to be surprised prevent surprised if a member of your party is surprised?" Is there a third question I'm missing that differentiate?

Comment: @NautArch Yes the Archer is rolling initiative (in the example he rolled a 21). The linked answer does not seem to cover the situation where the character that is not Surprised does not know the enemy exists. Maybe I should ask that as a different question to clarify?

Comment: @Lexaire If they are in combat initiative, why do they not know the enemy exists? That seems inherent in combat initiative. Initiative is initiative and surprise has specific mechanics.

Comment: I agree with @NautArch that this is a dupe of the first listed question (notice the [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/150289/62294) there is nearly the same as my answer here).

Answer (score 9):

#### The archer is not surprised and may act.

Surprise is a mechanic used to make sense of a particular narrative feature. It restricts what you are able to do on your turn in the initiative order, because narratively, you have been taken completely by surprise by your enemy.

So you take the alert feat - you are not *mechanically* restricted on your turn by being surprised, but your *in-universe* knowledge of the situation may or may not restrict what you *would* do.

So it comes down to roleplaying style. What does the ranger know about what is going on? What the archer does next is totally up to them. Do you act on player knowledge the character does not have? Do you play true to the narrative and act as though you have no idea combat has begun? That's a question for you and your players to discuss. But from a rules standpoint, the archer is not surprised and may take their turn.

#### Consistency of timing among a split party.

I would rule against rolling initiative only for the paladin and spiders because the timing of combat is quite precise - six seconds per round. I have to adjudicate the archer's actions in relation to the timing of the combat going on around the corner, and initiative is exactly how that is done. I want to maintain consistency in the timing of the archer's actions and the actions of the combat.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113538/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-markov-can-alert-prevent-surprise-if-you-dont-kn).